# Visualization of Intermediate represntation in Tf2

Tags: python, tensorflow

Referring to code below. What does the line `x = feature_map[0, :, : , i]` do in the code? Surely it slicing operation but why it is required. I am having really difficult time in understanding this, can anyone put forth their view. Thanks

```
  # Tile the images in this matrix
    display_grid = np.zeros((size, size*n_features))
    for i in range(n_features):
      x = feature_map[0,:, :, i]
      x -= x.mean()
      x /= x.std()
      x *= 64
      x += 128
      x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
```

Comment: What is `feature_map`?

Comment: Its an embedded matrix i guess, link here. https://pastebin.com/bQZJRk6R